# suppressing captions of figures but keeping list of figure captions?

Tags: table-of-contents, floats, captions

I have very long figure captions in a book. I use:

`\listoffigures`

to create a listing of these captions right after the table of contents. The figures themselves are given in each chapter. Is there a way to suppress the figure captions that now appear with the figure, but keep them in the `\listoffigures` listing? The figure captions are long and so they don't fit together with figures. Since the captions are listed already in `listoffigures` near table of contents the readers can simply refer to these and there's no need for `caption{}` to appear with figure, but I want that information to still get used for the listing. Is this possible?

Comment: Use an optional argument `\caption[]{}`

Comment: A floating figure should always have a caption; so the `\caption[<long>]{<short>}` way suggested by Sigur could be what you want.

Comment: @Sigur Can you make an answer?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

To use different captions for the same float use the optional argument

```
\caption[<opt>]{<main>}
```

So the `<opt>` will be used in the *List of...*  and the `<main>` will be used together the float.